# Getting a weird error when attempting to execute a simple program in Maven Web on Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, netbeans

I am currently just attempting to get NetBeans to work properly on Ubuntu.

Using Java-8
Just trying to launch a simple program that prints to the command line:
System.out.println("TEST");
Doing this from a package inside a Maven Web Project

The Error:
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/mavenproject1"): error=13, Permission denied -> [Help 1]

This works fine from an eclipse maven web project, and also runs fine from a maven java application, but not from the netbeans web application. I checked permissions, and it has read, write, and execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
- Set environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu) is guide for you.
- Set `MAVEN_HOME` variable in a similar way.

Comment: okie, try install Mavan proper way, then setting `MAVEN_HOME`.

Comment: Thanks for helping so far... I have done that.. still the same error in netbeans... but it works from command line... One thing I have noticed in netbeans is that when running through a web application it states that it is using the following executable: -Dexec.executable=java, while when running through a Java Application project it lists the following: -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java  ... it works fine through the Maven Java Application project, but not the Maven Web Application.

Comment: Since your project is web application, Do you setup application server (like Tomcat, GlassFish) in a proper way? Do you setup connector between Netbeans IDE with Java web application server in a proper way?

Comment: Yes glassfish is set up in the proper way... it works fine with eclipse, and the web part of the applications work fine as well. I just want to be able to run a class that may print something to the command line in the netbeans IDE from the web application itself, and that is when I get the above error.

Comment: also... running it from the command line with maven execute command works... but in the IDE it does not.

Comment: Reinstalled everything... Now it's working! Thanks for help!